# Enable and disable Alarms for WakefulIntentService

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

I am using [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) by @Commonsware.

In my implementation I want to be have an activity to enable/disable the Alarms. So my 2 questions are:

1. How can I manually enable/disable the Alarms from an activity using Button Click etc. (Alarms are set in the **onReceive** method of the **OnBootReceiver** class according to @Commonsware demo).
2. How to determine if Alarm is already set, so I don't enable/reschedule it again (i.e if alarm repeats every 5 minutes and I shouldn't reset at 1 minute before it was about to go off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I manually enable/disable the Alarms from an activity using Button Click etc

You set the alarms by calling `set()`, `setRepeating()`, or `setInexactRepeating()` on `AlarmManager`. You cancel the alarms by calling `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`.

> How to determine if Alarm is already set

There is no great way to do that, other than by maintaining that information yourself (e.g., in `SharedPreferences`).